# Why P(B|A) is not the same as P(A∩B) if both A & B are independent events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

If A & B are independent events and the order in which they happen doesn't matter, then why is P(B|A) is not the same as P(A∩B)?

P(A∩B) denotes the probability of A & B happening together.

P(B|A) denotes the probability that B would happen given that A has already happened. In essence, both A & B must happen and since both are independent events, P(B|A) should equal the probability of intersection.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Conditional probability rescales everything by the probability of the condition; in the definition $P(B \mid A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$. This makes sense from the point of view of applications, for example if you want to consider the probability that a patient who got a positive test is actually sick, this should be higher than the probability that they are sick with nothing else known. Independence flips it around, by saying that in fact the condition doesn't change the probability at all.

Comment: @Ian Could you please elaborate this in an answer? I've just started getting to know the ropes of probability.

Comment: Let us look at an example... I have ten boxes with marbles in it.  The first box has five red and five blue marbles.  Each of the remaining boxes have 9 red and 1 blue marble each.  I pick a box at random and then pick a marble from the box I picked.  The probability that I picked a red marble *given that* I picked the first box would be $\frac{5}{5+5}=\frac{1}{2}$.  All that conditional probability is here is looking at the probabilities when restricting ourselves to a smaller set of possible outcomes... here looking at what happens when we know we picked the first box.

Comment: We wanted a way to talk about the ways of picking a marble from the first box and looking at that $\frac{5}{5+5}$ calculation and giving a name to it... *that* is precisely what conditional probability is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then you expect that the occurrence of $B$ is not affected by the occurrence of $A$, and vice-versa. For example, suppose we roll two dice. The first number is not affected by the second one, nor the second one is affected by the first one. This is independence. This is why we write, for independent events: $$P(B|A) = P(B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)},$$ because $A$ does not influence $B$ to happen, so $P(B|A)=P(B)$. Now, $A\cap B$ is interpreted as the occurrence of $\textbf{both}$ events $A$ and $B$, and this is rather different than independence.